# Can we ask time-travel questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have an extremely curious question relating to [time-travel](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-travel) paradoxes which I believe has not been thought of before. Can I ask it in the main site?

Comment: *"which I believe has not been thought of before"* For myself I would not make a claim like that without an extensive literature search. Time travel fascinates everyone and a lot of smart people have been thinking about it for a long time.

Comment: @dmckee: I went ahead and asked it anyway http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/179520/
Tell me if you have ever heard of it before.

Comment: @RijulGupta I didn't see your question so I would guess either it was received bad and was deleted automatically or a mod deleted it

Answer (score 6):

You can ask questions on time travel in the framework of relativity or some other accepted theory, but you can't just ask about "time travel" in general. You need to be working in the framework of some theory. If it has absolutely nothing to do with an accepted theory in physics, it might still be relevant on [the scifi stackexchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/). If your question starts out with, "say you have a time machine", it probably isn't a good fit for physics stackexchange.

That's not to say that if you ask it, it will be voted up. There are are a *lot* of questions on this site about the "paradoxes" of special relativity already.